# What does this x86 assembly instruction do (addsd xmm0, ds:__xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000[edx*8])?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

Can someone explain what the following code does?

```
addsd   xmm0, ds:__xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000[edx*8]
```

I figured that some value is added to float register xmm0, but what is the meaning of __xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000 constant? Is there any documentation where I can read about it?

Here's the full fragment of code that I'm trying to understand:

```
cvtsi2sd xmm0, [ebp+var_2C8]
mov     edx, [ebp+var_2C8]
shr     edx, 1Fh
addsd   xmm0, ds:__xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000[edx*8]
```

ebp+var_2C8 is unsigned integer value.

1. ebp+var_2C8 is converted to float and moved to xmm0 register
2. ebp+var_2C8 is moved to edx and right shifted by 31 bit
3. something derived from this shifting is added to xmm0.

What exactly is added to xmm0?
Is there a possible purpose to this calculation?

**Update.**

Here's the raw disassembly for this code:

```
cvtsi2sd    xmm0,dword ptr [ebp-2C8h]  
mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-2C8h]  
shr         edx,1Fh  
addsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [edx*8+2685CC0h]
```

Looks like some double value from array of constants is added to xmm0...

Comment: It's a lookup table or array. The silly constant is just a product of your disassembler (could also be a symbol), look at the raw disassembly to see the actual address.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the conversion of unsigned integer to double.

How it works is it first converts it as signed, meaning that the sign bit has a weight of -2<sup>31</sup>, but it should be unsigned where the top bit has a weight of +2<sup>31</sup>. So if the sign is set, it adds +2<sup>32</sup> = 4294967296.0 (41f0000000000000 as double) to compensate. It does so by shifting right, putting the top bit in the bottom bit and clearing everything else, and then it uses that as a table index into a table containing 0 and 4294967296.0.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this thorough explanation!